# cannot read characters of a string except for the first one calling a c procedure from r

Tags: c, r

I am trying to pass strings from r to c and want to reach individual characters of the string.

So far, I could read the first character and string as whole however, reaching anything after the first character of the string I passed from R caused R interpreter to crash.

Here is the c code

```
void test(char** str1) {
    printf("%s\n", *str1);
printf("%c\n", *str1[0]);
//printf("%c\n", *str1[1]); // without this, it works fine.
}
```

Here is the R code

```
str1 = "foo"
returned_data = .C("test", as.character(str1))
```

I am totally clueless. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parenthesis

```
printf("%c\n", (*str1)[1]);
//             ^     ^
```

Without the parenthesis you're accessing the second element of an 'array' of `char *`.